# How can I test SMS using AWS SNS (boto3/moto) in Python/Django?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, boto3, moto

I'm working on an API that sends SMS in some endpoints using AWS SNS. In tests that touch these endpoints, the `mock_sns` decorator is used. However, no assertions are made regarding the number or content of the SMS messages sent. I suppose this is only there to avoid errors. In my case, however, I actually need to check that one SMS message was sent and that it contains a specific text. How can I do that? How should my test look like?

I know how to do it using plain Python mocking but since the project already has `moto` as a dependency I figured I'd give it a try, but I'm surprised I couldn't find any example of such a simple use case. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the purpose of this library?

```
@mock_sns
def test_my_endpoint():
    response = client.post("/my/endpoint/", ...)
    # assert one SMS was sent???
    # assert "FooBar" in SMS???
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use the moto library, why not use sqs to test that only one notification has been sent using sns?

The sns + sqs connection, sometimes called as [fanout](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/send-fanout-event-notifications/), will achieve the specified test as the notification will be stored in sqs and you can check it right after the call. Check the test_fanout method below.

On the other side and with the information provided, I would use [botocore stubs](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html) or python mocks to check that the call is already made the way you want. In case of using stubber, check the test_stubber_sms method below.

The code assumes moto >= 1.3.14, boto3 1.18, botocore 1.21.0 and python 3.6.9:

```
from moto import mock_sns, mock_sqs
import unittest
import boto3
import json
from botocore.stub import Stubber


class TestBoto3(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock_sns
    @mock_sqs
    def test_fanout(self):
        region_name = "eu-west-1"
        topic_name = "test_fanout"
        sns, sqs = boto3.client("sns", region_name=region_name), boto3.client("sqs", region_name=region_name)

        topic_arn = sns.create_topic(Name=topic_name)["TopicArn"]
        sqs_url = sqs.create_queue(QueueName='test')["QueueUrl"]
        sqs_arn = sqs.get_queue_attributes(QueueUrl=sqs_url)["Attributes"]["QueueArn"]

        sns.subscribe(TopicArn=topic_arn, Protocol='sqs', Endpoint=sqs_arn)
        sns.subscribe(TopicArn=topic_arn, Protocol='sms', Endpoint="+12223334444")

        sns.publish(TopicArn=topic_arn, Message="test")
        sns.publish(PhoneNumber="+12223334444", Message="sms test")

        message = sqs.receive_message(QueueUrl=sqs_url, MaxNumberOfMessages=10)["Messages"]
        sqs.delete_message(QueueUrl=sqs_url, ReceiptHandle=message[0]["ReceiptHandle"])

        self.assertEqual(len(message), 2)
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(message[0]["Body"])["Message"], 'test')
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(message[1]["Body"])["Message"], 'sms test')

    def test_stubber_sms(self):
        sns = boto3.client("sns")
        stubber = Stubber(sns)

        stubber.add_response(method='publish', service_response={"MessageId": '1'}, expected_params={'PhoneNumber':"+12223334444", 'Message':"my message"})
        with stubber:
            response = sns.publish(PhoneNumber="+12223334444", Message="my message")
            # Or use your method and pass boto3 sns client as argument
            self.assertEqual(response, {"MessageId": '1'})
            stubber.assert_no_pending_responses()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a direct way to do this as there is no such API call in the `boto3` library.
What you can do, is to create a subscriber (mock), register to the sns and assert on the subscriber. Examples of such tests can be found in the internal tests of `moto` iteslf:

```py
@mock_sns
def test_publish_sms():
    client = boto3.client("sns", region_name="us-east-1")

    result = client.publish(PhoneNumber="+15551234567", Message="my message")

    result.should.contain("MessageId")
    if not settings.TEST_SERVER_MODE:
        sns_backend = sns_backends["us-east-1"]
        sns_backend.sms_messages.should.have.key(result["MessageId"]).being.equal(
            ("+15551234567", "my message")
        )
```

From: https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_sns/test_publishing_boto3.py